# How can I delete a file of the primary filegroup (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, filegroup

I have a database with a lot of tables and I created a new file in the primary filegroup, I haven't inserted any new data yet but when I try to delete this new file, I get this error

> The File ‘newfile’ Cannot be Removed Because it is Not Empty

How can I delete this file?

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic652585-146-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the solution was as Mitch Wheat indicated in the link that he showed.
I had to empty the file using:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(newfile,EMPTYFILE)
```

then it can be eliminated using:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME REMOVE FILE newfile
```